# Надписи перекрываются на вкладке активности

Tags: дефект

На вкладке актиность на графике репутации надписи перекрываются. Подробнее на скриншоте[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Посмотрел код. Слёзы навернулись. Кровавые, правда. Вроде недавно делали, вроде технологии простые, а вышло... Блин, пару дней с самоучителем и лучше сделаешь.

Comment: Было уже. Смотрите в дефектах. С мобильного не удобно пока искать.

Comment: Искал, но только на последней вкладке, не думал, что он такой старенький...